# Seeking Guidance on Moving Applications and Files from one Virtual Machine to Another

Tags: virtual-machines

I'm using a service that provides virtual machines via VMWare.  I have an older VM who's OS and tools need to be upgraded.  However, I also have tons of applications, files, web server and other stuff that cannot be deleted.

Since the machines are on the same subnet, I was wondering if I could establish a network connection on the new VM to the old one and transfer files and apps that way?  Or is there a better method of doing this?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant you take a backup then just upgrade the OS and tools? If anything goes wrong then you have a snapshot of the machine before?

I would think that would be the easy way rather than trying to transfer a lot of data around.

Thanks
William

Answer (score 0):

The fact that these are VMs has nothing to do with your problem or the solution. You would do this the same way you would do this if it were physical machines. Since you don't mention the OS, I can't give you any specifics at all - if your OS supports an in-place upgrade and your apps will still be compatible with the new OS version, then do that - after, as William Fleming says, taking a backup first.

Comment: It's a Windows 2008 R2 VM, and I'll be migrating to Windows Server 2012 VM.  In place migration/upgrade is not possible due to the hosted VM environment.

Comment: An upgrade of a Win2k8 R2 machine to Win2012 is technically possible. If your hosting vendor is preventing that due to policy, you should work with them to see what their recommendations are. There's no way to transfer applications under Windows between machines - you'll need to do new installations of everything on the new server. Files can be copied of course - and again, that has nothing to do with any VM technology.